# NFC details using Flutter

Tags: flutter, nfc, payment, emv

How can i read NFC credit cards details like card number, expiry date and cvv using Flutter.I have tried using packages like [flutter nfc kit](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_nfc_kit) and [Nfc manager](https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager) but it doesn’t seem to do what i want.

```
Future<void> readCardData() async {
    try {
      // Check if NFC is supported on the device
      bool isAvailable = await NfcManager.instance.isAvailable();
      if (!isAvailable) {
        throw Exception('NFC is not available on this device');
      }

      // Start the NFC session
      await NfcManager.instance.startSession(onDiscovered: (NfcTag tag) async {
        Ndef? ndef = Ndef.from(tag);
        if (ndef == null) {
          throw Exception('Tag is not compatible with NDEF');
        }

        // Read NDEF message from tag
        NdefMessage message = await ndef.read();
        if (message == null) {
          Get.snackbar('Error', 'Tag is empty',
              snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM);
          throw Exception('Tag is empty');
        } else {
          // Parse the message and extract card data
          NdefRecord record = message.records.first;
          String payload = String.fromCharCodes(record.payload);
          List<String> fields = payload.split('|');
          if (fields.length != 4) {
            throw Exception('Invalid card data format');
          }

          cardNumber = fields[0];
          cardHolderName = fields[1];
          expiryDate = fields[2];
          cvv = fields[3];

          // Update the UI with the card data
          update();
          Get.toNamed(
            '/debit-sms',
            arguments: receiveController.text,
          );
        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Credit card (in general payment cards) are not as simple "data storage" cards like e.g. an USB-Stick. You need to "talk" with the card, select an application on the card, ask for processing options and retrieve a "file address list" (the correct name is "AFL" application file locator). Then read the files, parse the content and find a file where the PAN (primery account number) is stored in. Sounds complicated but it is not that magic. Good luck with Flutter (I can't help you further because I'm working on Android/Java.

Comment: is it possible using something like this

 var cardNumberResponse = await tag.transceive(Uint8List.fromList([0x00, 0xB2, 0x01, 0x0C, 0x00]));

Comment: To get card details like the "card number" you have to run some commands in a sequence as mentioned before, so **you can't get the card number in one read**.

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting as a response because I don't enough reputation to make a comment.

I don't have too much experience with Flutter, but helped in a similar thing in ReactNative, you can find the repo [here](https://github.com/thiagosprestes/skia-cards).

Obs: It is **not** possible to read the CVV from a card trough NFC.

The steps are the following:

1. You need to get the IsoDep reference to the NFC Tag (this lib may help: https://pub.dev/packages/nfc_manager)
2. Send an APDU Command to the card in order to select the PPSE and list all the applications
3. Send an APDU Command to the card to select the application you want to extract the data
4. Build the PDOL (list of informations the card request from the reader in order to proceed)
5. Parse the AFL (list of records the card has available to be read)
6. Read all the record and filter for the specific tags you want (5A is the card number and 5f24 is the expirationDate)

All those steps are being done in ReactNative on the repo I shared starting [here](https://github.com/thiagosprestes/skia-cards/blob/3b4e0ac12c5d4aa2d4519b9e6d838c6aad45fc06/src/hooks/useReadCard.ts#L47)

Comment: Does this work for IOS?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Apple does not allow applications to access payment applications on smartcards for apps that are not on their Tap to pay program.